# Looking for Lambda function to move files to different S3 buckets based on file type

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

Does this exist out there before I go hacking away at it.  Still new to lambda and wrapping my head around it so any pointers on methodology would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't mention what's the event against which you want to trigger lambda? Is it file creation in S3 i.e. when a file is created in S3, you want to copy it to a another path according to its file extension?

Comment: Sorry it would be on file creation and yes after a file is uploaded it would move somewhere else based on file extension.

Answer (score 2):

Since, you didn't mention the language you'd want the Lambda to be in, I'll use Python.

```
def handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = record['s3']['object']['key']
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(key)
        if extension == '.foo':
            dest = <s3_key_1>
        else:
            dest = <s3_key_2>
        copy_key(key, dest)
```

In Python, you'd use Boto to copy objects from src to destination key.